# How do I embed a responsive website inside a website without losing website design responsivness?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

Hi I have a responsive designed website embedded into another website.  But the problem is that on mobile devices and tablets the embeded website dosent respond to the device window size. Code posted below.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

div {
    height: 99%;
}

object {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}       
</style>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#siteloader").html('<object data="www.responsivesite.com" />');

});
</script> 


</header>



<body>

<div id="siteloader"></div>








</body>






</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an iframe to embed another page. The media queries will then be treated based on the width of the iframe. For example,

window width - 480px
iframe width - 100%
@media (max-width:480px) will trigger.

window width - 480px
iframe width - 80%
@media (max-width:480px) will not trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Put this on the head of the html

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

[Source](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/ConfigureViewport?hl=en)